# Strings being inappropriately escaped when put into text fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, escaping

In our Rails 3.2.13 app, we have this code in one of our ERB views:

```
<script language="javascript">
function copy_address ()
{
    document.getElementById("account_firm_name").value = '<%= escape_javascript firm_name %>';
    document.getElementById("account_address_line_1").value = '<%= escape_javascript address %>';
    document.getElementById("account_city").value = '<%= escape_javascript city %>';
    document.getElementById("account_state_id").value = '<%= escape_javascript state_id.to_s %>';
    document.getElementById("account_zip_code").value = '<%= escape_javascript zip %>';
}
</script>

<%# snip %>

<%= form_tag %>
  <table>
    <tr class="two_columns">
      <td><label for="firm_name">Firm Name*</label></td>
      <td><%= text_field 'account', 'firm_name' %></td>
    </tr>
    <%# snip %>
  </table>
</form>
```

It's a Rails form and a JS function that copies some known values into the form.

If there are any special characters in the `firm_name`, `address`, `city`, or `zip` strings that are injected by ERB, they are inappropriately HTML escaped. For example, if `firm_name = '&'`, then the generated HTML includes the JS function:

```
<script language="javascript">
function copy_address ()
{
    document.getElementById("account_firm_name").value = '&amp;';
    // snip
```

and executing the function inserts the string `&amp;` (not `&`) into the corresponding text field in the form.

Is there a safe way to prevent ERB from escaping the values of the strings or a way to use JavaScript to un-escape the strings before putting them into the text fields?

(So far, I've tried using the `.html_safe` and `raw` Rails methods, but no dice.)

Comment: How about printing out a JSON encoded object then use that in JavaScript?

Comment: Could you use `sanitize` in the controller, then you wouldn't have to `escape_javascript` in the view

Comment: @n_i_c_k: I recently added the `escape_javascript` trying to get it to work. The behavior is the same without those calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that elsewhere in the view, we had this code:

```
<% firm_name = h(@agency.name) %>
<% address = h(@agency.address) %>
<% city = h(@agency.city) %>
<% state_id = @agency.state_id %>
<% zip = h(@agency.zip_code) %>
```

If you're having the same problem I did, make sure that you don't have any code pre-escaping the strings you want to use.

I ended up using this code:

```
function copy_address ()
{
    document.getElementById("account_firm_name").value = '<%= raw (escape_javascript @agency.name) %>';
    document.getElementById("account_address_line_1").value = '<%= raw (escape_javascript @agency.address) %>';
    document.getElementById("account_city").value = '<%= raw (escape_javascript @agency.city) %>';
    document.getElementById("account_state_id").value = '<%= raw (escape_javascript (@agency.state_id.to_s)) %>';
    document.getElementById("account_zip_code").value = '<%= raw (escape_javascript @agency.zip_code) %>';
}
```

using the `@agency` attributes directly, before they had been run through `h()`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when trying to dynamically set a page's title element. I ended up deciding which characters I wanted to check for and just doing a `gsub` in a view helper like so:

in application_helper.rb

```
def title_sanitize(string)
    sanitize(string).gsub('&amp;', '&').html_safe
end
```

Then in your view

```
document.getElementById("account_firm_name").value = '<%= title_sanitize(firm_name) %>';
```